# Modal loading before HTTP Get request angular 2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, modal-dialog

I have a table of data. When i click the row of the table Http call for the id is sent and a modal will open with the data. But the modal is not getting the data. I have the response but i think the modal is rendering before the response. How can i display the data into the modal on click?

Template:

```
Table : 
<div class="table-responsive">
      <div class="table table-striped">
        <table class="table table-striped" id="emp_address_list">
          <thead>
            <tr class="sub-header">
              <th>
                Address
              </th>
              <th>Type</th>
              <th width="15%">Status</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>

          <tbody id="address-list" *ngIf="addressData == null"><tr><td colspan="4" align="center">No Active Records Found.</td></tr></tbody>

            <tbody id="address-list"  *ngIf="addressData">
              <tr *ngFor="let full of addressData " class="{{full.status}}style show-{{full.status}}" data-target="#address-details-modal" data-toggle = "modal" (click)="seperateId(full.ID)">
                <td class="{{full.status}}style show-{{full.status}}"  >
                  {{full.address1}} {{full.address2}}
                </td>
                <td class="{{full.status}}style show-{{full.status}}">
                  {{full.type}}
                </td>
                <td class="{{full.status}}style show-{{full.status}}">
                  {{full.status}}
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>

        </table>     
      </div>
```

modal:

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

          <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9 emp-panel-group current-row emp-tab-bottom-margin" id="address_div"  >
    <dl class="dl-horizontal" *ngIF="addressid" >             
      <dt>Address:</dt><dd> {{addressid.address1}} </dd>
      <dt>Type:</dt><dd>{{addressid.type}}</dd> 
      <dt>Notes:</dt><dd>{{addressid.notes}}</dd> 

      <dt>Created On:</dt><dd></dd>              
    </dl>

  </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
```

HTTP call:

```
seperateData(id) {
                const eurl='http://localhost/Angular/AddressSeperate.php?id='
                const url= `${eurl}${id}`
                return this.http.get(url)
                .map(this.extractData)
                .catch(this.HandleError)
            }
```

Comment: Where's the http call?

Comment: https://github.com/shlomiassaf/angular2-modal  http://plnkr.co/edit/ZAZqZu?p=preview https://github.com/shlomiassaf/angular2-modal/tree/master/src/demo

Comment: I am getting the response but the data is not getting into the modal when opened. I am sending an HTTP call on click of the table row.  I kept a ngIf for the data to render if the data is present. I am getting the response from the server but the data is not rendering. I think the Modal is opening even before the service responds. What should I do in this case? Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

In your template for the modal, look at this line:

```
<dl class="dl-horizontal" *ngIF="addressid" >
```

Change the casing of `*ngIf`

Comment: I changed it. Thats not the case.